# Why firebase give this error when I use onSnapshot?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> Error itself : Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'pa', but it was: a custom $n object

firebase file :

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'AUTH_DOMAIN',
  projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
  appId: 'APP_ID',
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)

export { db, auth }
```

Request itself :

```
useEffect(() => {
    //getPosts()
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'cities'), (snapshot) => {
      const postsList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data(),
      }))
      setPosts(postsList)
    })
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])
```

I tried to change some imports like other recommend but just got another error

Comment: Do you import the methods with `import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";`? (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firestore Lite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/firestore-lite) SDK does not support listeners. Try importing `getFirestore()` from the standard SDK.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore' // <-- remove /lite

const firebaseConfig = {...}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)

export { db, auth }
```

```
import { db } from './path/to/firebase';
import { collection, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'cities'), (snapshot) => {
    const postsList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data(),
    }))
    setPosts(postsList)
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: When I do this i get this error :Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Comment: @Pickez can you please edit your question and show latest code? Include all import and export statements of both the files. Also try restarting your dev server

Comment: Oh sorry I change import collection in the same way , thank you so much